# Mule documentation pdf version

Tags: mule

Does any one know where can I get Mule latest version documentation in PDF format? I have been searching for it, I found chapert-6 Mule entry point resolver sets in PDF format. That means other chapters are also should be there but I couldn't fine myself. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a pdf version of the documentation yet. If you want you can either save the documentation pages to download the different sections or you can look at the book [Mule in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617290823). For more information you can check out [here](http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/pdf-documentation).

Comment: Hi clare thanks for replying but I have found some chapters in PDF format, you can take a look at this link https://www.mulesoft.com/sites/default/files/working-with-components.pdf

Comment: That is an old version of the documentation since it is based on services. As of Mule 3.3.x or 3.4.x, the services are no longer being used.

Comment: In case if you know, can you provide me the links to other chapters, even it is old version also it's ok.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an enterprise license, you can download the complete used guide from customer support portal in PDF format.